# Big issue with custom post type wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Basicly I got a custom post type declared in the functions.php:

```
register_post_type("butik", [
    "labels" => [
        "name" => "Butik",
        "singular_name" => "Butik"
    ],
    "show_ui" => true,
    "supports" => [
        "title",
        "editor",
        "thumbnail"
    ]
]);
```

I got all the posts rendered out correctly on my custom listing page, HOWEVER.. I want them to displayed on a single.php template when they are clicked aswell. I have googled for ages and reading everywhere that i'm supposed to create a single-butik.php for my case and be able to list each appropriate post there, but it's not working. Its just directing me to index.php template, so I tried listing them out there, with no success, tried printing out the posts there, no success.....

What am I doing wrong?!...

One example of a permalink for a custom post is : 
http://localhost:8080/caroli/butik/caroli-blommor/

Any tips or solutions?

Comment: Double check your file hierarchy. Best would be create a copy of single.php first and renamte it to single-bukit.php this will minimize the chances of error.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Buddy. I have tried with only single.php, only single-butik.php, only index.php, or all together... I don't get it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add 'public' => true, and:
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'butik')  keys

```
register_post_type("butik", [
    "labels" => [
        "name" => "Butik",
        "singular_name" => "Butik"
    ],
    "show_ui" => true,
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => 'butik'
    ],
    "supports" => [
        "title",
        "editor",
        "thumbnail"
    ]
]);
```

And after that go to settings -> Permalink Settings and just click "update button".

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually due to the rewrite rules needing to be updated.  WordPress isn't always good about doing that automatically.  Try these steps (in this order):

1. Go to Settings > Permalinks and change the structure to "Custom Structure".  (It should default to "http://yourdomain.com/%postname%/).  Make sure you click "Save Changes".  Check and see if your custom post type is now using the single-butik.php template.  If it is NOT, then:
2. Open up your functions.php and add the following code:

   ```
   function theme_prefix_rewrite_flush() {
      flush_rewrite_rules();
   }
   add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'theme_prefix_rewrite_flush' );
   ```

Save your functions.php and, in the WordPress admin switch your theme to 2014 (or any other default theme) and activate it.  Now switch your theme back to what it is supposed to be.  This will force a flush of the rewrite rules.

One way or another your custom post type should be using the correct single-butik.php template.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me the best solution for custom post type is [acf plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) he ll do all this job for you, just read docs first and then you can do templates as you like.

I hope this will help you :)